# How many letters are needed for a bingo in 9 tile Scrabble?

Tags: scrabble

When playing the 9 tile variant in scrabble do you need to play all nine tiles at once for a bingo or just 7 tiles as per the regular rules.

Comment: You're playing a variant: so make up your own rule with whomever you're playing with, agree to it; and stick to it.

Comment: We'd need to know which 9-tile variant this is. If the only information is that it's a variant with 9 tiles, we can't really tell you how the bingo also works.

Comment: The 9 tile variant of scrabble is very common, and has only two modifications to the rules, a 9 tile rack, and bingos are scored on 7, 8, and 9 letter words.

Answer (score 4):

The 9 Tile Rack variant of scrabble hasn't been included in an official rule book yet, so there isn't a canonical source; but whenever it's included in a non-official source it includes a 50 point bingo for *7, 8, and 9 tile words*.

See [UltraBoardGames](https://www.ultraboardgames.com/scrabble/variants.php), the [Scrabble project](https://scrabbleproject.weebly.com/scrabble-instructions.html), or [gamerules.com](https://gamerules.com/rules/scrabble-board-game/)